# Azure artifact - DLL's are inside a subfolder in the zip

Tags: azure-devops

I have trouble deploying a .NET core Web API to Azure App Service with Release Pipeline, after some investigating, I found the issue is the files (DLL's) I need to deploy is archived inside a zip file with many levels of directories, the files are under

```
Content/D_C/a/1/s/my-project-name/obj/Release/net7.0/PubTmp/Out/
```

I am not sure in Release Pipeline, how to extract files from the directory above and zip files up again ?

Comment: Could you share your pipeline with us?

Answer (score 0):

Again I figured it out myself.... I end up updating my build pipeline, instead of creating a zip file, just specify a OutputPath in build task and publish all files as artifact

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/out"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'


- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/out'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```